# Can I do anything to mitigate GDI resource leakage in Windows?

Tags: windows, gui, resources, gdi

There's a problem on all Windows systems that there's a limitation on graphical primitives that can be used system-wide. Which leads to the following: once I've started several (actually something like 25+) GUI-rich apps like Visual Studio or Internet Explorer I can't open any more windows - depending on how the application reacts to this either nothing happens or an error is reported.

Is there anything I can tune in Windows to at least make the upper limit on these primitives higher?

Comment: it's not a "leakage", it's a "limit"

Comment: Makes me wonder why you need 25 instances of Visual Studio at any one point in time.

Comment: Well, it's quite typical to have say 5 instances of VS for looking "how that works" in other projects, Outlook and multiple IE instances. This can be enough to hit the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724291(VS.85).aspx). It explains how to increase the limit of GDI objects in your system

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725486(VS.85).aspx) explains how to increase the limit of User object.

Comment: Both links only give pointers how to change the per-process limit. This won't affect the system-wide limit which is what the OP is running into. The limit of 10k handles for a single process is quite ample by default. VS only eats up around 500 of them.

Answer (score 3):

This [Microsoft NTDebugging article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ntdebugging/desktop-heap-overview) explains at length how the **Desktop Heap** can be exhausted and prevent opening additional windows.  Indeed, this was THE crucial solution to my own problem of opening an extreme amount of programs on a Windows 2000 and Windows XP workstation.  I had to increase my "3072" value to "8192" before I fixed it, after that, I've NEVER run out of handles again, even with 310 Chrome Tabs open simultaneously plus about 20 other applications on a 4GB RAM WinXP 32-bit system.

Comment: I don't know about you, but my Chrome nearly grinds to a halt once I get past ~100 tabs on 4GB Windows 7...

Comment: I'm up to 1,018 tabs in 26 Chrome windows now on my 4GB WinXP 32 bit system. Yes I know that's insane. You should monitor via ProcExp to see if CPU, disk, or Flash process are your bottleneck. 100 tabs is nothing for a smooth running system!

Comment: Does everything grind to a halt when you try switching tabs, or is it all smooth? I'm betting it has something to do with my graphics drivers...

Comment: It's all smooth now that I have my pagefile on an SSD.  Before that I was using 8GB Commit on a 3.3GB RAM 32-bit system.  Now I can use 9GB Commit and it doesn't even slow down since the SSD pagefile accesses are so fast.

Comment: Ah, you have an SSD, that explains it... lucky bastard ;)